# Counting "page views" or "hits" when using cache

Tags: python, django

I have a view called `show_board`. Inside it, among other things, I increment a field `Board.views` by 1 every time it is run, to count page views.

The problem is that when I use the @cache_page decorator on that view, `Board.views` is only going to get incremented every time a new cached view gets generated, and not every time that view is requested, like I want to.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually write another decorator to achieve this.

```
def view_incrementer(view_func):
    """A decorator which increments board views"""

    def _wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        # here you can increment Board.views
        # kwargs will contain URL parameters
        pk = kwargs.get('pk')
        Board.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(views=F('views')+1)
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

    return _wrapped
```

Then apply the decorator to your view function/method:

```
@view_incrememter
@cache_page(timeout=60)
def show_board(request, pk):
    ...
```

Or you can use it directly in your urls.py

```
url(r'^some-path/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', view_incrementer(cache_page(60)(show_board))),
```

Comment: This worked fantastically. I'm a little lost however when it comes to the use of _wrapped inside the decorator: what does `_wrapped` return exactly, and why must it be done in this nested way? Thank you very much.

Comment: _wrapped returns view_func evaluated. Here is a simplified example: `view_incrementer(show_board)` will return _wrapped, where view_func is show_board. When _wrapped is called, board.views in incremented, and show_board is called and returned.

Comment: There is an excellent guide to decorators which may help you understand this answer better at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/386221. Python decorators are a powerful construct and well worth your time to learn :)

Comment: This is not working for me, it still changes only when cached page times out, can you help?